# How to achieve a 'hidden' communication between 2 windows phone 8.1 apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, communication, application-lifecycle

I am developing 2 apps in WP 8.1.

One should send requests(I call it "sender") and the other one should answer on them (I call it "receiver"). Both will be installed on the same WP device.

The perfect solution will be the one that user will not see in the UI that some "communication" is happening with different application. 
But no matter how I try, the turnstile animation is displayed whenever "sender" hide/get visible.

[I removed splash screen, set transitions to null. However even if I close the receiver immediately (after the LaunchUri was called) I still can see the turnstile animation]

Imagine this example:

1. "sender":
   User will click on "test button" and this code will be called:

   ```
   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myreceiver:giveMeYourSecret"));
   ```
2. in "receiver"

   as the answer on this code:

   ```
   await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mysender:MySecretPassword"));
   ```

   and closes itself.
3. in "sender":
   MySecretPassword is displayed in some TextBlock.

I know that this example is nonsense. I just need to achieve communication between 2 apps without any "not-wanted animations"(like turnstile).

My Questions:

1. Is there another way how to communicate between 2 windows phone 8.1 apps than via LaunchUri?
2. Is it possible to remove turnstile animation when the app is being resumed/deactivated ?

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Use a WCF service: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893352/Using-WCF-Service-in-Windows-Phone

Comment: I can not use this approach, I need to have the communication also "offline". Plus if I use this approach: sender -> WCF service -> receiver -> WCF service -> sender. This solution will also cause the "not wanted" animations(+ push notifications can have a long delays)